# why other clauses after "IF" is not working, when nested in while loop finishes

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, nested

hi I am trying to create very simple if else clause which has nested while loop like this.

```
    a = 10
    if a > 6:
        while a > 5: 
            a -= 1
            print("a in while loop")
    elif a == 5:
        print("a", a)
    else:
       print("Doing else")
```

The issue is when while loop finished, it will not go elif nor else clause.
I think I am missing something basic here. Could someone explain?
I thought after while loop finished the code should check rest of the statements.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The `elif` clause in an `if` statement is simply a cleaner way to write an `else` clause with an additional `if` statement, so your code is actually equivalent to:

```
a = 10
if a > 6:
    while a > 5: 
        a -= 1
        print("a in while loop")
else:
    if a == 5:
        print("a", a)
    else:
        print("Doing else")
```

which means that once `a > 6` is evaluated as `True`, it would not enter the `else` block at all, no matter what happens in the `if` block, so whether or not the value of `a`
changes in the `if` block does not affect the already evaluated expression `a > 6` in the `if` clause and would not help the execution enter the `else` block.

If you really want `a == 5` to be evaluated after the `while` loop, you should use a separate `if` statement rather than an `elif` clause:

```
a = 10
if a > 6:
    while a > 5: 
        a -= 1
        print("a in while loop")
if a == 5:
    print("a", a)
else:
    print("Doing else")
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)